$a,b,c$ are non-zero reals such that $(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)\neq0.$ Prove $\left|\frac a{b+c}\right|+\left|\frac b{a+c}\right|+\left|\frac c{a+b}\right|>1$
Any hint is appreciated.
I tried AM≥HM.
Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb R^\times$ such that $(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)\neq0.$ Prove $$\left|\frac a{b+c}\right|+\left|\frac b{a+c}\right|+\left|\frac c{a+b}\right|>1$$

Please do not include unnecessary images and instead use MathJax to format your question.  Here is a tutorial.

What have you tried?

I tried A(|a|/|b+c|, |b|/|a+c|,|c|/|a+b|)≥H(|a|/|b+c|, |b|/|a+c|,|c|/|a+b|) and what I got could not be simplified

Put your work in the question. People will close a question if you don't show any attempt, and they shouldn't have to read through the comments to see your work.

This looks like a weaker nesbitt - I suspect you can replace $3/2$ instead of $1$.
You do need to explain why you can assume all variables are positive

Ok Thomas Andrews & thanks. Thank you agent_cracker103

Hint: Use Nesbitt's Inequality which states that
$$\frac{x}{y+z} + \frac{y}{x+z} + \frac{z}{x+y} \geq \frac{3}{2}$$
and
$$\left| \frac{a}{b+c} \right| \geq \frac{|a|}{|b| + |c|}, \quad \left| \frac{b}{a+c} \right| \geq \frac{|b|}{|a| + |c|}, \quad \left| \frac{c}{a+b} \right| \geq \frac{|c|}{|a| + |b|}$$
So
$$\left| \frac{a}{b+c} \right| + \left| \frac{b}{a+c} \right| + \left| \frac{c}{a+b} \right| \geq \frac{|a|}{|b| + |c|} + \frac{|b|}{|a| + |c|} + \frac{|c|}{|a| + |b|}$$
